AdminJS error: Component "PasswordEditComponent" has not been bundled, ensure it was added to your ComponentLoader instance
I'm creating an admin panel with AdminJS, Node.js, Express.js, and MongoDB. When setting up the resource for users, I get an error when trying to render the password field:
enter image description here
I'm using the default components from ComponentLoader. Here is the code from the user.resource.ts file:


import argon2 from "argon2";
import passwordsFeature from "@adminjs/passwords";
import { User } from "../models/index.js";
import AdminJS, { ActionRequest, ComponentLoader } from "adminjs";

const componentLoader = new ComponentLoader();

const UserResource = {
  resource: User,
  options: {
    properties: {
      password: { isVisible: false },
      newPassword: {
        type: "string",
        isVisible: { list: false, filter: false, show: false, edit: true },
      },
    },
    actions: {
      edit: {
        before: async (request: any) => {
          if (request.payload.newPassword) {
            const hashedPassword = await argon2.hash(
              request.payload.newPassword
            );
            request.payload.password = hashedPassword; 
            delete request.payload.newPassword; 
          }
          return request;
        },
      },
      new: {
        before: async (request: any) => {
          if (request.payload.password) {
            const hashedPassword = await argon2.hash(request.payload.password);
            request.payload.password = hashedPassword;
          }
          return request;
        },
      },
    },
  },
  features: [
    passwordsFeature({
      properties: {
        encryptedPassword: "password",
        password: "newPassword",
      },
      hash: argon2.hash,
      componentLoader,
    }),
  ],
};

export default UserResource;



This is the code in index.ts:


import AdminJS, { ComponentLoader } from "adminjs";
import AdminJSExpress from "@adminjs/express";
import express from "express";
import session from "express-session";
import * as AdminJSMongoose from "@adminjs/mongoose";
import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
import { Category, Post, Product, User } from "./models/index.js";
import argon2 from "argon2";
import UserResource from "./resources/user.resource.js";

const PORT = 3000;

const componentLoader = new ComponentLoader();

AdminJS.registerAdapter({
  Resource: AdminJSMongoose.Resource,
  Database: AdminJSMongoose.Database,
});

const start = async () => {
  const app = express();

  await connectDB();

  app.use(
    session({
      secret: "mysecret", 
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: { secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" }, 
    })
  );

  const adminOptions = {
    resources: [UserResource, Category, Post, Product],
  };

  const admin = new AdminJS(adminOptions);

  const authenticate = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (user && (await argon2.verify(user.password, password))) {
      return user; 
    }
    return null; 
  };

  const adminRouter = AdminJSExpress.buildAuthenticatedRouter(
    admin,
    {
      authenticate: async (email, password) => {
        const user = await authenticate(email, password); 
        if (user) {
          return { email: user.email, role: user.role }; 
        }
        return null; 
      },
      cookieName: "adminjs",
      cookiePassword: "example" , 
    },
    null,
    {
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      secret: "sessionsecret", 
      cookie: { secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" }, 
    }
  );


  app.use(admin.options.rootPath, adminRouter);

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(
      `AdminJS started on http://localhost:${PORT}${admin.options.rootPath}`
    );
  });
};

start();



And here is the package.json file:


{
  "name": "admin-wellfit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "admin for wellfit project",
  "main": "./index.ts",
  "author": "OF",
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "tslib": "^2.7.0",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@adminjs/express": "^6.1.0",
    "@adminjs/mongoose": "^4.1.0",
    "@adminjs/passwords": "^4.0.0",
    "adminjs": "^7.8.13",
    "argon2": "^0.41.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "express": "^4.21.0",
    "express-formidable": "^1.2.0",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.6.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "tsc && nodemon --no-warnings dist/index.js"
  }
}



These are the errors in the console:
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
I'm not sure if I'm implementing the resources correctly. I've researched and read the documentation, but I can't find a solution to render the fields to hide and modify the password correctly. If anyone could help me identify the issue and implement the resource properly, I would greatly appreciate it.

Hi, could you include the full error log or traceback from the development console mentioned in your screenshot? This additional detail will make it easier to identify the issue and provide a more accurate solution. Thanks!

Thank you for reply, i already paste the images of the errors in the console
